# How to to use Angularjs with Magento?

Tags: magento, angularjs, magento-1.7

I've been asked to develop an Magento site with angularjs.  I'm not really sure how to go about it, is there anyone out there with experience of using both who could give me some advice on how to implement it?

Are there any useful tutorials for integrating them?  I found [this](https://github.com/Wildhoney/Magento-on-Angular) project on Github, I might try this.

Do Angularjs & Magento work well together?

Comment: See this: http://www.webspeaks.in/2014/03/integrating-angular-js-with-magento.html

Answer (score 5):

Well angular.js is a  JavaScript framework and there should be no issue using angular.js for integrating the frontend part of magento. AngularJS needs you to bootstrap the html file, so you will be required to make changes in the html tag of the pages which can be found in `app/design/frontend/default/[theme]/template/1column.phtml` and other base phtml files (`2column-left, 2column-right and 3column`).

Once you are done bootstraping AngularJS you will be required to calll the Angular.JS file for the pages which you can do in `app/design/frontend/default/[theme]/layout/page.xml` using the `addJs` action method.

Now your website should have bootstrapped and called the AngularJS, now you can use it in any of your phtml files, this should work.

In case you wish to replace prototype.js which is the default JavaScript framework magento uses then it should be a major work around.